# I need to override the class Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Util/ModuleResolver/ModuleResolverService.php

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I was trying to override the Class Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/DataTransport/Auth/WebApiAuth.php function getAdminToken() but this particular function is a static function so it can't be override so I tried overriding the class
Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Util/ModuleResolver/ModuleResolverService.php from where this function getAdminToken() is called so that I can call the function getAdminToken() of my custom class WebApiAuth.php.
I tried overriding the class by preference

but the class is not getting override ,I need to make change in this function
public function getAdminToken(): string rather than calling the function getAdminToken() of class
Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\DataTransport\Auth\WebApiAuth; I want to call my custom file.

I tried using the preference

but was unable to get die inside my custom file when I am running the command in the Terminal
php -d memory_limit=-1 vendor/bin/mftf generate:tests AdminLoginSuccessfulTest, it is getting die in the core file but not in my custom override file.

Comment: I have some fun time while trying to override functions of Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework too. I couldn't find out how to do it and I didn't want to spend time investigating it deeper. I would suggest you find an alternative. May I ask what you are trying to do?